# change specific image of listview

Tags: android

I am trying to click on specific images on list_view I am having 5 images in a row, what I want is that if i click any image then it should get changed with other image from drawable. 
But the issue is that when i click on image then the specific is not changing instead other images get changed.

### section of adapter where i am trying to change image

```
if(Feedback_activity.listView.isItemChecked(i)){
        viewHolder.imageView_1.setImageResource(R.drawable.vb1_selected);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create an interface for that, for eg. if onClickListener is set on the listView item, inside the onClick method you can write the logic to change the image.

Comment: sir I've tried listeners also but same problem is occuring. ( Other images are changing)

Comment: Could you post the code of the adapter where you are making the changes?